# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 7) - ignoring files that do not meet this requirement - python

Tags: python

I am trying to code something that will open a file and look through it to rename specific sections of file names. So far I can successfully rename what I want in the correct manner I am looking for. The problem arises when a file in the folder does not contain enough values to be unpacked. Is there a way to ignore this file? I dont need to rename it if it does not meet the requirements that I have, but I do need the file to remain in the folder. Here is what I have:

```py
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\for12\Desktop\Arid West\LC08_CU_008009_20140902_20190504_C01_V01_SR")

for f in os.listdir():
    filename, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_sat, f_cu, f_tile, f_sdate, f_date, f_1, f_2, f_band = (filename.split('_'))

    if f_band.startswith("SRB"):
        f_band = f_band.strip()[2:]

    new_name = '{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}{}'.format(f_sat,f_cu,f_tile,f_sdate,f_date,f_1,f_2,f_band,filename_ext)

    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

[image]

This image shows the .xml that is causing the issues as I have the file being split by a "_" and it only contains 7 instead of 8.

Answer (score 3):

Let's work with a simplified example:

```py
names = ['a_b_c', 'd_e_f', 'g_h']
```

Instead of trying to unpack the values right away, we can just keep the result of the `split` as a list. Then, we can check if the length of the list is what we expect and only then do further processing on it:

```py
for name in names:
    items = name.split('_')
    if len(items) == 3:
        print('{}.{}.{}'.format(*items))
```

This gives us:

```
a.b.c
d.e.f
```

Here we used the unpack operator (`*`) to unpack the values of the list into individual arguments for the `format` method.

With this approach, if you wish to pass additional explicit arguments to `format`, they will need to come before the unpacked arguments. To address this, we can use positional arguments in the format string `{}`-placeholders. Here is an example:

```py
for name in names:
    items = name.split('_')
    if len(items) == 3:
        print('{1}.{2}.{3}.{0}'.format('txt', *items))
```

This gives us:

```
a.b.c.txt
d.e.f.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
try:
  f_sat, f_cu, f_tile, f_sdate, f_date, f_1, f_2, f_band = (filename.split('_'))
except ValueError:
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split file firstly to some variable and then check length of it.
Like this:

```
file_parts = filename.split('_')
if len(file_parts) < 8 or len(file_parts) > 8:
   continue # ignore such files
```

Or handle exception that it raises (`ValueError`):

```
try:
  f_sat, f_cu, f_tile, f_sdate, f_date, f_1, f_2, f_band = filename.split('_')
except ValueError:
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it this way maybe:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a, b, c, d, e, f, *other = l

if other:
    g = other[0]
```

What this code does is it does basically the same, only it unpacks 6 elements and anything else in the list that over 6 elements are stored in `other` variable. Then if `other` is not empty you can assign it where you need.

But I think that this approach is a little bit cleaner than `try/except` but stil it requires that you know how many variables you expect.

What I would do is I would create the new file name like this:

```py
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\for12\Desktop\Arid West\LC08_CU_008009_20140902_20190504_C01_V01_SR")

for f in os.listdir():
    filename, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    some_list = filename.split('_')
    some_list = [str(s) for s in some_list]

    for l in some_list:
        if l.startswith("SRB"):
            l = l.strip()[2:]

    new_name = '_'.join(some_list)
    new_name += filename_ext

    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

This should solve unpacking errors because this way you will not care about how much values the file name will have and you still be able to update the `f_band`. With a list comprehension, I'm securing that `'_'.join(some_list)` would not crash as it expects `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). This way your code will be simpler and more concise. To solve this problem, you can use the method [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and your code will look like this:

```py
import os
import re

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\for12\Desktop\Arid West\LC08_CU_008009_20140902_20190504_C01_V01_SR")

for filename in os.listdir():
   new_name = re.sub(r"(\_SRB)(\d+)\.([^\.]*)$", r"_B\2.\3", filename)
   os.rename(f, new_name)
```